# How to get url string params in Web2Py?

Tags: python, web2py

Really stupid question here... but I can't seem to figure it out.  In PHP when passing url params for say:  www.mysit.com/index?name=steve I would use:

```
$_GET["name"]
```

In web2py I know you can get stuff via `request.vars.someNameAttribute` for stuff like what text is within a  box.  But how do I get params straight from the url string?  Specifically I have form like this:

```
<form action="add_comment?idnum=5">
     <input type="text" name="comment_text"/>
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In the controller `def add_comment()`, how do I get that the idnum is 5???  I've been trying `request.vars.idnum` but this doesn't return anything.  Am I not calling it right?  Or is there some issue with the way I'm passing it in the "action" attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, figured it out.

`request.vars.idnum` is indeed the way to go... it just wasn't working because the method attribute of  was not set to "post".